# How to filter dimension from another dimension in tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dimensional-modeling

Question in Tableau:

I have a list of products and category and subcategory, what i need is: show sales by products of a subcategory, while the product is selected from a parameters which has list of products.

I want to add this parameter as a master filter for my dashboard where i can show the current Qtr sales for the product, in another chart i want to show the trend of products in the subcategory.

Currently when i try to do a filter from dashboard, the second chart with trend shows up only for the selected product not its class of product.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the specific sheets that are affected from dashboard filter actions.
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_filter.html

If you are not using a dashboard action, you can also configure which sheets a filter applies to.
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_global.html